# Error while taking backup of the Database

Tags: sql-server-2008

[image: Screenshot of the error i got during taking backup]

Hello every one,

While taking back up of the database, i got the above error. I know their will be two files log file and data file. the error showing that the media file needs to take a back up. How can i do that.

Could any one please help me doing this.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but more likely the error tells you that you are attempting to backup the database into 2 destinations at once, while the database is formatted to support only 1.

Comment: @Andriy: post this as an answer, it sounds logical you backup usually  one bak file

Comment: @Andriy M: hello, i have selected the  below path for backup.

Comment: @Shine: No, you haven't. You've only highlighted one of the items. The backup process will still use both.

Comment: @Andriy M : thanks alot:-) I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The destination list in the backup dialogue contains all the items that are going to be used by the backup process. If you mean to use just one, you must *leave* one in the list and remove all the others.